# Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject error in Java using mondodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongodb's async driver 3.0.2 (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/) with Java.

I am trying to find the 10 closest documents to a place. The following query I would use in a mongodb shell to accomplish this:

```
db.locations.find( { loc : 
                  { $geoWithin : 
                    { $centerSphere : 
                       [ [ 40 , -40 ] , 10 / 3963.2 ] 
                } } } ).limit(10);
```

I need to though run this in java so created the query below, but when I run it I get this exception:

`org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.`

**CODE:**

```
BasicDBObject geometery = new BasicDBObject("$centerSphere", asList(
                        asList(40, -40), 10 / 3963.2));
                BasicDBObject operator = new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin", geometery);
                BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("loc", operator);

                Block<Document> postsBlock = new Block<Document>() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(final Document document) {
                        System.out.println(document.toJson());
                    }
                };
                SingleResultCallback<Void> postsCallback = new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println("Operation Finished!");
                    }
                };

                try {
                    collection.find(query).limit(10).forEach(postsBlock, postsCallback);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

In your connection you need to specify the codec registry `com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()` should do fine

For the async driver

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().readPreference(readPreference)
    .codecRegistry(com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()).socketSettings(sockSettings)
    .connectionPoolSettings(connPoolSettings).credentialList(credentials))
    .clusterSettings(clusterSettings).build();
LOG.info("MongoClientSettings: {}, {}, {}, {}", sockSettings, connPoolSettings, clusterSettings, credentials);
MongoClient mgc = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

for the normal driver

```
MongoClientOptions settings = MongoClientOptions.builder().readPreference(readPreference)
    .codecRegistry(com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()).build();
MongoClient mgc= new MongoClient(servers,credentials,settings);
```